# Can we relax hypothesis of Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $F$ is continuous  $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in [a,b]$. Assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Then Fundamental theorem of calculus say that

$$F(x)-F(a)=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt$$

> My Question is: Can we say that $$F(x)-F(a)=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt$$ hold true if we  remove the assumption that $F$ is differentiable at  $a$ and $b$.

My thoughts: The proof uses the mean value theorem to prove the theorem but mean value requires only that $F$ is continuous $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: "The proof" ... it is not because you learned one specific proof that there is only one ...

Comment: @LL3.14: Thanks. Do you mean we  FTC still hold if we remove  differentiability at end points

Comment: Since it holds on $[a+{1 \over n},b-{1 \over n}]$, if $F$ is continuous at $a,b$ then taking limits gives the desired result.

Comment: You wrote $F(x)-F(x).$

Comment: The question is quite poorly written. It is not really clear to me what you are asking exactly. To me, the most general statement in this direction would be Lebesgue's density theorem, giving this result as soon as F is absolutely continuous (or f locally integrable).

Answer (score 2):

There are other versions of the fundamental theorem of Calculus that are in the spirit of what you wrote. Some require extensions to the Riemann integration, which are beyond the scope of a first year college Calculus class. The most common extension in mathematics is [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration), there is also a less common but also useful extension, called  gauge integration develop independently by  several people: Denjoy, [Henstock-Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) and others.

---

In  Lebesgue integration these are mainly two results:

**Theorem 1L.** If $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is absolutely continuous, then $F'$ exists $\lambda$--a.s., is integrable (in the sense of Lebesgue) over $[a,b]$, and
$$
F(x)-F(a)=\int^x_a F'(t)\,dt, \quad a\leq x\leq b.
$$

**Theorem 2L.** Let  $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be  continuous. If $F$ is  differentiable on $[a,b]$, with the exception of a countable set pf points,   and  $F'$ is integrable (in the sense of Lebesgue, never mind the set of exceptional points where $F'$ is not defined) then,
$$
F(x)-F(a)=\int^x_a F'(t)\,dt,\quad a\leq x\leq b.
$$

---

For the Henstock integral, there is a version similar the Theorem 2. above

**Theorem 2H:** Suppose
that the function $F$ is continuous  differentiable at all
but a countable collection of points in $[a,b]$. Then its derivative $F'$ is integrable (in the sense of Henstock-Kurzweil) on $[a,b]$, and
$$
F(x)-F(a)=\int^x_a F'(t)\,dt,\quad a\leq x\leq b.
$$

---

Theorems 1L, 2L   are studied in courses of Lebesgue integration.  A good source at the undergraduate level is Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis book.

A good place for the study of this type of integral is Bartle's book "Modern theory of integration". This type of integration can be done in a way that is similar to Riemann integration.

---

Answer (score 2):

A stronger version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is given in the following paper:

Michael W. Botsko and Richard A. Gosser, "Stronger Versions of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus",
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 93, No. 4 (Apr., 1986), pp. 294-296.

**FTC**: Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, and let $g$ be a continuous function
on $[a, b]$ such that $g'_{+}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a, b)$ where $g'_{+}(x)$ is the right derivative. Then
$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} x = g(b) - g(a)$.

Remark: By the way, I need it when I encountered the following problem.

Suppose $f: [0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is non-decreasing and concave, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that
$$\frac{\int_0^1 f^2 \mathrm{d} x}{\int_0^1 f \mathrm{d} x} \ge \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: +1 for letting us know that the right derivative thing is sufficient.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apostol gives the theorem in following manner

> **FTC**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and let $g:(a, b) \to\mathbb {R} $ be such that $g'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in(a, b) $. Then the limits $$\lim_{x\to a^{+} } g(x), \lim_{x\to b^{-}} g(x) $$ exist and we have $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x) - \lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) $$

Thus essentially you don't need the $F$ in your question to be differentiable (or even continuous or defined) at end points $a, b$.

---

On request of user @sani via  comment I give a proof of the above mentioned theorem.

Let $$F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt\tag{1}$$ Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ it is bounded on $[a, b] $ and let $M$ be an upper bound for $|f|$ on $[a, b] $. Then $$|F(x+h) - F(x) |=\left|\int_x^{x+h} f(t) \, dt\right|\leq M|h|$$ if both $x, x+h$ lie in $[a, b] $. This proves that $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $.

Consider $g$ defined on $(a, b) $ such that $g'(x) =f(x) $ on $(a, b) $. Let $c\in(a, b) $. By the usual FTC we have $$g(x) =g(c) +\int_{c} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ for all $x\in(a, b) $ and using $(1)$ we can write above equation as $$g(x) =g(c) +F(x) - F(c) \tag{2}$$ Since $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ we can see the limits of RHS of $(2)$ as $x\to a^+$ and as $x\to b^{-} $ exist and we have $$\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) =g(c) +F(a) - F(c) $$ and $$\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x) =g(c) +F(b) - F(c) $$ Subtracting these two equations we get $$F(b) - F(a) =\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x) - \lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) $$ Note that $F(a) =0$ and $F(b) =\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ via definition $(1)$ and the proof for the above mentioned theorem is complete.

Comment: Hiiii. Can you please give me the source where I will get the proof of that statement?@Paramanand Singh

Comment: @sani: no big deal. Will update my answer to include proof. Wait for a few minutes.

Comment: @sani: check updated answer.

Comment: Thank You @Paramanand Singh. But in [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763182/int-a-b-fx-dx-lim-x-to-b-gx-lim-x-to-a-gx/3763189#3763189] we are not sure that $f(x)$ is Rieman integrable or not  since it is not defined at $x = 0$. Then how would I apply this theorem there?

Comment: @sani: $f$ is given to be Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.  Also I don't get the context of "not defined at $x=0$".