# How to find $\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x}\,dx \,$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, solution-verification

> How to find
> $$\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x}\,dx \,\,?$$

The integrand $ \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x} $ is not defined at $x =0$. But the function is bounded on $(0 , \frac{\pi}{2}]$.
$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x} = 0$$  So **this is not an improper integral**.

**My Attempt** :
$$\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x} = \lim_{t \to 0} \int_t ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x} = \lim_{t \to 0}  \left[(\frac{\pi}{2} - 1)+ (\tan{\frac{t}{2} - t})\right] = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 1\right)$$.

I know how to find the anti-derivative of the integrand. I first found out the anti-derivative of the integrand in $[t , \frac{\pi}{2}]$ , where $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Let's say it is $\phi(t)$. Then I find $\lim_{t \to 0} \phi(t)$.
I am not sure if this is a right way. Can anyone please check it?

Comment: Your attempt looks correct to me.

Comment: Since the integral is proper you don't need to take limits. Rather try to find a function $F$ which is continuous on $[0,\pi/2]$ and the derivative $F'$ equals the integrand on $(0,\pi/2)$. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus then says that the integral is $F(\pi/2)-F(0)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3754943/72031 for the statement of FTC.

Comment: Can you please give me the proof of this link's theorem? I am quite curious to see how it is being possible..@ParamanandSingh

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + cosec x} dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x} dx=\pi/2-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+\cos x} dx$$ $$=\pi/2-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sec^2(x/2)~dx=\pi/2-\tan x |_{0}^{\pi/2}=\pi/2-1.$$

Comment: I know how  to solve it. I was asking about the point $0$ where the integrand  is not defined. This is also not an improper integral. Is my attempt fine? 2Dr Zafar

Comment: But the function in the first place is not defined at $x = 0$.

Comment: I do not think You can  change the function for your convenience in this way.

Comment: @sam for the integral to exist either $f(0)$ or $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) $ should be finite. So in your case $ f(x)=\frac{\cot x}{\cot x+\csc x}$, $f(0)=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (undefined), but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$, by L-Hospital's rule, or just by simplifying $f(x)$.

Comment: Can I do the way I have done in the attempt? @Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Comment: @sam Yes, it is correct. But it is better to simplify your integrand to make it well defined at lower/upper limit and in between, if you can.

Comment: @sani: it does not matter if the integrand is not defined at a finite number of points. At those points you can define the function in any manner. However what is more important that the function remains bounded and the interval of integration is also bounded. Otherwise we need to use the idea of improper integrals.

Answer (score 0):

my solution
$$\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x}{\cot x + \csc x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot x(\csc x-\cot x)}{\csc^2 x-\cot^2x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \csc x\cot x-\cot^2 x)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2} \csc x\cot x-\csc^2 x+1)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=(-\csc x+\cot x+x)_0^{\pi/2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

Comment: I know how  to solve it. I was asking about the point $0$ where the integrand  is not defined. This is also not an improper integral. Is my attempt fine? @Jyee Fischer

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cot\pars{x} \over \cot\pars{x} + \csc\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{x} \over \cos\pars{x} + 1}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{2\cos^{2}\pars{x/2} - 1 \over
2\cos^{2}\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{1 - {1 \over 2}\sec^{2}\pars{x \over 2}}\,\dd x =
\left.x - \tan\pars{x \over 2}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \pi/2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over 2} - \tan\pars{\pi \over 4} =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{{\pi \over 2} - 1}\ \approx\
0.5708
\end{align}

Comment: I know how  to solve it. I was asking about the point $0$ where the integrand  is not defined. This is also not an improper integral. Is my attempt fine? @Felix Marin

Answer (score -1):

HINT:  Take , $$\cot x- \csc x=t$$

then, $$\cot x+ \csc x=\frac{1}{t}$$

and $$\cot x=\frac{1}{2}\left[t+\frac{1}{t}\right]$$

I think you can proceed from here.

Comment: I know how  to solve it. I was asking about the point $0$ where the integrand  is not defined. This is also not an improper integral. Is my attempt fine?

Comment: @sam That is why I reshuffled  (simplified) the integrand which is finite everywhere in $[0,\pi/2]$. For example $frac{x}{x+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x}$ is finite at $x=0$.

Comment: At $x = 0$ , what is $t = ?$@Venkat Amith

Comment: At $x=0$ then $t=$,

  $cotx- cosecx=t$ ,

$\frac{cosx-1}{sinx}$,

$t=-Tan(\frac{x}{2})$

then $t=0$ at $x=0$.

@sani