# Prove $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x) - \lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone tell me how to prove the following theorem.

Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and let $g:(a, b) \to\mathbb {R} $ be such that $g'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in(a, b) $. Then the limits $$\lim_{x\to a^{+} } g(x), \lim_{x\to b^{-}} g(x) $$ exist and we have $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x) - \lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. By integrability, $|f|$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by some constant $M\geq 0$. It follows that the function $g$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$: for $a<x\leq y<b$:
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq \left|\int_x^y f(x)\,dx\right|\leq M|x-y|$$
which implies that the  limits $\lim_{x\to a^{+} } g(x)$, $\lim_{x\to b^{-}} g(x)$ exist.

By the same reason, as $r\to 0^+$,
$$0\leq \left|\int_{a} ^{a+r} f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \int_{a} ^{a+r} |f(x)|\,dx\leq Mr\to 0$$
and
$$0\leq\left|\int_{b-r} ^{b} f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \int_{b-r} ^{b} |f(x)|\,dx\leq Mr\to 0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes now I can complete.@Robert Z